# uploading work in jupyter to github

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and just got started few months ago.

I am using spyder in anaconda for python programming. I want to upload my work in github but it seems to be less presentable than the other files uploaded which are written in using jupyter notebook. can any one suggest me some way to get over this.

I have been working on spyder since one year. i dont think moving from this is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create repository in github, create new pull/ clone from github using sourctree, gitkraken or etc, and then put .git folder to your project folder, then update the sourctree/gitkraket or etc with new project, then commit changes and push to github. :) It always works for me if I'm stuck...